# How to customize default export option in material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) and I want to remove the default CSV & PDF export option.

I would like to have only an excel option.

How can I change the menu ?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: means you remove `export as pdf` and rename text from `export as csv` to `export as excel`?

Comment: Yes. Eventually I want to export the table data in excel format.

Comment: csv is excel format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Defining `options` on the MT component like this will allow you to show/hide each option:

```
  options={{
      // ..other options
      exportButton: {
        csv: true,
        pdf: false
      }
   }}
```

Also, you could use `localization` settings to rename the label of each option like this:

```
 localization={{
      toolbar: {
        exportCSVName: "Export some Excel format",
        exportPDFName: "Export as pdf!!"
      }
    }}
```

It looks like the official docs are a bit outdated, so I found the answer to what you were looking for on these threads in GitHub:

- [exportButton](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/2323)
- [localization](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/2253)

Working sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-export-options-evc7n?file=/src/App.js). Good luck!

Comment: Perfect! I was also using old version which didn't have this option. Thank you

Answer (score 12):

For custom CSV and PDF, you should define `options`

```
 options={{
    exportButton: {
       csv: true,
       pdf: true,
    }
 }}
```

and for the handlers should be defined more options

```
 options={{
    exportButton: {
       csv: true,
       pdf: true,
    },
    exportCsv: (data, columns) => console.log(data, columns, '<== CSV'),
    exportPdf: (data, columns) => console.log(data, columns, '<== PDF'),
 }}
```

in the handler function for the CSV you can use `filefy` package

```
import { CsvBuilder } from 'filefy';
```

and for PDF you can use `jspdf` and `jspdf-autotable` packages

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
```

*also handler examples*

```
exportCsv: (data, columns) => {
  const columnTitles = columns
      .map(columnDef => columnDef.title);
  
  const csvData = data.map(rowData =>
        columns.map(columnDef => rowData[columnDef.field]),
      );

  const builder = new CsvBuilder(`data.csv`)
        .setColumns(columnTitles)
        .addRows(csvData)
        .exportFile();

  return builder;
}
```

```
exportPdf: (data, columns) => {
  const doc = new jsPDF();

  const columnTitles = columns
      .map(columnDef => columnDef.title);
  
  const pdfData = data.map(rowData =>
        columns.map(columnDef => rowData[columnDef.field]),
      );

  doc.autoTable({
     head: [columnTitles],
     body: pdfData,
  });

  doc.save(`data.pdf`);
}
```